# How to get rid of the error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-vr

I created an iOS application with the Google VR pod. I setup everything in the Viewcontroller and storyboard. When I try to run this project I get the error:

`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.
What should I do? Xcode says you have to enable bitcode, but is there another way to do this, without changing `ENABLE_BITCODE`?

Looking forward for some solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually due to some pod missing that you are adding in your pod file.Or due to not opening the project by xcworkspace after adding the pod.Try opening it from xcworkspace or add pod properly.